# How to move alot of objects by "Force Field" each one in a different speed

Tags: particles, hair, force-fields

I have created a plane and above it i have applied "hair" using as particles any number-shaped objects.
After i have converted each one particles in one object making them "Rigid Body" (Active).
After i have created a "Force Field" (Wind) in the direction of numbers.
But each one object has the same speed, i would like that each one object has a different speed.
One idea can be give a different weight to the object but is a too long work. What do you think?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Giving each object a unique weight is the right idea and can be done with two lines of code.

The following loops over every object in a collection, generating and assigning a random mass value between 0 and 1 for each object.

```
    import bpy
    import random
    
    
    for obj in bpy.data.collections['obs'].all_objects:
        obj.rigid_body.mass = random.random()
```

If you want to specify limits on the values of mass, the following sets each object's rigid body mass to a random value between 0.2 and 0.5:

```
    import bpy
    import random
    
    
    for obj in bpy.data.collections['obs'].all_objects:
    obj.rigid_body.mass = random.uniform( 0.2 , 0.5 )
```

This is straight forward within Blender:

1.Make sure all your objects are in their own collection - here I've named it 'obs'

[image]

2. Open a new text editor window:

[image]

3. Create new text file:

[image]

4. Add code, using the name of your collection ('obs' in this case) then click the run button to execute.

[image]

Comment: Thak you very mach. I'm very suprised it works perfectly. Are you copy this code or you know Phyton?